# How to use for loop for pandas moving windows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe, I applied pandas moving window method.

```
moving = df.rolling(150, win_type='triang').mean()
```

The above line of code can calculate moving window means, but I dont want the mean of each moving window. I need to apply for loop to process each moving window, something as the following:

```
for x in moving:
    #do some process
```

Is there any efficient method to do this in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a function in each window by using the `apply` method.

```py
moving_windows = df.rolling(150, win_type='triang')

def do_process(window):
    #do some process


window_results = moving_windows.apply(do_process)
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html

Comment: Apply method can be used , but in my case i am interested to use simple for loop

Comment: You asked what is the efficient way. Can you be more specific? Which efficiency are you looking for? Tiime, space, code maintainability, readablity?